# How to use multiple if conditions for Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use multiple conditions in my pandas, but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

As per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) I replaced the `and` with a bitwise operator, but I am still getting the error.

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'Year': [2019,2019,2019,2019,2019], 'Week':[1,2,4,6,7], 'Value': 
[20,40,60,75,90]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

if (df1['Year'] == df1['Year'].shift(-1)) & \
 (df1['Week'] == df1['Week'].shift(-1)):
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
```

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: You're trying to use regular python boolean checks with Series objects. You can't do that. You're asking for an implicit boolean: What should Python say to `if [1, 2, 3] and [2, 3, 4]:`? That'd be `True` but it wouldn't tell you anything about individual rows (values in the list).

Comment: What is your actual desired output?

Comment: Thanks, @roganjosh. I get it now. I want to output 'No' for each row in the dataframe.

Comment: As in, a new column? If you want to iterate the DF and print things row-wise then it really doesn't fit well with Pandas and could be done with just regular lists.

Comment: Yes. A new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual comparison check is not incorrect but doesn't work with regular Python `if` because Pandas works in a vectorized manner. As I said in the comments in regards to the error:

> What should Python say to `if [1, 2, 3] and [2, 3, 4]:`? That'd be `True`
>   but it wouldn't tell you anything about individual rows (values in the
>   list)

Instead, use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
df1['comparison'] = np.where((df1['Year'] == df1['Year'].shift(-1)) & 
                             (df1['Week'] == df1['Week'].shift(-1)), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Comment: Is np.where always recommended to be used with pandas for conditional statement?

Comment: @Shantanu if you're trying to do row-wise comparisons without a `for` loop (which you should try avoid if possible), then yes. But it's tough to answer that because pandas and numpy are _huge_ and there could be all sorts of tricks. If you're just starting out then yes, the simplest way is to think of it like this.

Comment: If you have one condition, it is the fastest way, specially if you want to yield different values depending on the result of the condition

Comment: @Wen-Ben wouldn't that drop into a python `for` loop on `map`?

Comment: @Wen-Ben but those docs are also suggesting `apply` which definitely does drop vectorization and go row-wise in "python time" so I suspect it would be much slower. I wouldn't personally go for that approach myself but you're free to post as an alternative :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which will yield `Yes` or `No` according to whether the condition is met or not:

```
c1 = df1.Year == df1.Year.shift(-1)
c2 = df1.Week == df1.Week.shift(-1)
df1.loc[:,'is_repeated'] = np.where(c1&c2, 'Yes', 'No')

   Year  Week  Value    is_repeated
0  2019     1     20          No
1  2019     2     40          No
2  2019     4     60          No
3  2019     6     75          No
4  2019     7     90          No
```

Comment: What is the downvote for? Please I'd appreciate a reason in order to improve on my answer or know what I've done wrong

Comment: I was just about to ask the same

Comment: some times there is no reason from them :-( give both of yours my vote @roganjosh

Comment: Not from me though. :)

Comment: For the nice use of `np.where` to you and my all time fav @roganjosh  : +1

Comment: Thx @Bazingaa :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not very sure about the bitwise operator, but to compare arrays you can use the `equals` method and logical `and` together, I think that would be easier.

For example, you can modify the loop condition to:

```
if df1['Year'].equals(df1['Year'].shift(-1)) and df1['Week'].equals(df1['Week'].shift(-1)):
```